# Как реализовать приоритетную очередь?

Tags: java, c++, python, алгоритм, очередь

Задача состоит в том, чтобы написать программу читающую из файла описания операций с очередью и выводящую в другой файл результат выполнения всех операций extract-min. Если перед очередной операцией extract-min очередь пуста, выводит вместо числа звездочку.

Пример:

```
priorityqueue.in                                             priorityqueue.out

push 3                                                       2
push 4                                                       1 
push 2                                                       3 
extract-min                                                  *
decrease-key 2 1
extract-min
extract-min
extract-min
```

Я написал реализацию с использованием списка, куда каждый элемента добавлял с бинарным поиском, чтобы массив был всегда отсортирован

```
import bisect, sys
sys.stdout = open("priorityqueue.out", "w")
queue = []
operations = open("priorityqueue.in").read().strip().split("\n")
for op in operations:
    op_parsed = op.split()
if op_parsed[0] == "push":
    bisect.insort(queue, int(op_parsed[1]))
elif op_parsed[0] == "extract-min":
    try:
        print(queue[0])
        del queue[0]
    except:
        print("*")
else:
    del queue[int(op_parsed[1]) - 1]
    bisect.insort(queue, int(op_parsed[2]))
```

Но проблема в том, что на некотором тесте была "ошибка времени исполнения". Как я выяснил эмпирическим путем на строчке `del queue[int(op_parsed[1]) - 1]` кидается исключение и скорее всего это было `IndexError`, но из-за чего оно кидается я понять не могу.

До этого я написал реализацию с использованием `heapq` у которой тоже была "ошибка времени исполнения" на том же месте

```
import heapq, sys
sys.stdout = open("priorityqueue.out", "w")
queue = []
operations = open("priorityqueue.in").read().strip().split("\n")
for op in operations:
    op_parsed = op.split()
    if op_parsed[0] == "push":
        heapq.heappush(queue, int(op_parsed[1]))
    elif op_parsed[0] == "extract-min":
        try:
            print(heapq.heappop(queue))
        except IndexError:
            print("*")
    else:
        queue[int(op_parsed[1]) - 1] = queue[-1]
        queue.pop()
        heapq.heappush(queue, int(op_parsed[2]))
```

P.S. При попытке добавления блока

```
try:
    ...
except:
    pass
```

"ошибка времени исполнения" заменяется на "неверный ответ" на том же тесте

Comment: А разве у decrease-key аргументы означают индекс в очереди? Наверняка это значение элемента который нужно изменить, получается вам нужно найти вначале элемент с заданным значением и потом уже его уменьшить, последний аргумент у команды наверное означает на сколько уменьшить найденный элемент. И вообще у вас нигде нет проверок на некорректные значения, нужно проверять всегда ли есть такой элемент, также думаю нужно проверять правильное ли имя команды, также что в команде нужное число аргументов.

Comment: Кстати если тестирование говорит вам что превышение по времени, то наверное как раз медленный алгоритм, если бы было исключение необработанное то наверное бы тестер сказал об аварийном завершении программы. Возможно задача требует более быстрого алгоритма, чем даже Куча. Можете привести полный текст задачи, интересно же нам тоже её порешать :).

Comment: Кстати во втором решении с кучей действие `queue[int(op_parsed[1]) - 1] = queue[-1]` у вас замещает элемент на значение последнего элемента в массиве, т.е. в массиве будет теперь два одинаковых значения, по идее это портит инвариант кучи, т.е. куча уже не будет после этого валидной, нужно как-то иначе это делать. С невалидной кучей нельзя гарантировать что остальные операции будут правильно работать.

Comment: не ясно, что `decrease-key 2 1` делает на основе примера (уменьшает на 2 элемент 4, который второй (индекс 1) по величине в очереди или который был добавлен вторым в очередь?)

Answer (score 1):

В команде `decrease-key 2 1` второй элемент это значение элемента в куче, а не его индекс в ней. Используй в командах `push 3` значения больше, чем предположительный размер кучи и скрипт повалится раньше.

Делай так:

```
del queue[queue.index(op_parsed[1])]
```

А ее лучше, если заменишь `del` на `.pop()`:

```
queue.pop(queue.index(op_parsed[1]))
```

Comment: это не может быть значение: в примере в ку че находятся 3 4, когда `decrease-key 2 1 вызывается